# how to clear error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

How to clear the following error:

> Only one instance of a ScriptManager
>   can be added to the page. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Only
>   one instance of a ScriptManager can be
>   added to the page.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception
>   was generated during the execution of
>   the current web request.
>   Information regarding the origin and
>   location of the exception can be
>   identified using the exception stack
>   trace below.

The following is my html Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"   
    CodeFile="ManualReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="ManualReport" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" 
    tagprefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Content  ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" 
    ID="ContentPlaceHolder1">

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<form id="mainform" runat="server"><table width="100%" >
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

</form>

    <div>
         <tr><td>Customer Name</td><td>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbcustomerAll" runat="server"  Visible ="false"   
 GroupName="CustomerValidation" 
                 Text="All" Checked="false" /></td><td>
             <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbcustomerSpecific" runat="server"  
  GroupName="CustomerValidation" Visible="false" Text="Spec" Checked="true" /></td></
  td><td>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbName" runat="server">
                     </asp:DropDownList></td></tr>
                     <tr><td>Date</td><td><asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDateAll" runat="server" 
  Visible ="false" GroupName="DateValidation" 
                 Text="All"  /></td><td>
             <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbDateSpec" runat="server" Visible ="false" Checked="true" GroupName="DateValidation" Text="Spec" /></td><td>
        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpDate" runat="server" xmlns:telerik="telerik.web.ui">
                              </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                     </td></tr>
```

Comment: You have a serious issue structuring your aspx markup. That's beyond the issue of `ScriptManager` duplication. I believe that you need to read some tutorial about asp.net. A lot of them ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you add the `ScriptManager` two times on your page? You can only add one, and that's what the error says. Only one ScriptManager instance is allowed per page.

Please remove the `ScriptManager2` and it will work for you.

Secondly ScriptManger should be under Form Tag. like..

```
<form id="mainform" runat="server"><table width="100%" >

  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>

</form>
```

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar i have remove one script manager and same problem occured

Comment: Which one you removed ? ScriptManager2 should be removed , as this is in out of form tag.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar i had remove  ScriptManager2 that be a same problem how to clear

Comment: Muhammad Akhtar i have update your answer but errorOnly one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page. 
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.

Comment: @Malliga; I guess you add the script manager  on Master page. There should be only one Script Manager on Master Page or Content Page. If you have add SCript Manager on master page, then remove all the script manager from content page, as this is not required on adding on every page.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar - apologies, did not see your comment until after posted my answer...

Comment: @Dave Long; Its OK no problem.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar i have update my code  same problem occured.

Answer (score 1):

`ScriptManager` is a server side component and it has to be placed inside a `form` tag. Only one `ScriptManager` component must be added per page. In your case, you have provided two `ScriptManager` components. Therefor, you have to remove one of them, the `ScriptManager` which resides outside the `form`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two script managers in the page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

and

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Per the description of the error, you have to remove one. You may only have one.

Comment: i have remove the one script manager and same problem occured

Comment: We'll need to see more then. The error message is quite blatant.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the answers the others have already give, which are 100% correct, you are also closing your "form" too early...

```
<form id="mainform" runat="server"></form>
```

Move the closing "form" tag to AFTER all your Server side ASP.NET controls, ensuring your HTML remains valid... (difficult to know exactly where to without seeing your full markup, but I would guess close to the closing Content tag : /asp:Content)

EDIT: Actually, also worth pointing out that because you are using a master page here, you probably already have a server side form inside your master page... You cannot then have a second form inside the aspx child page aswell.  I would suggest maybe putting your Single Script manager into your master page, inside the form tag, as the others have pointed out, and removing all references to script manager and "form" from the child (aspx) page) ?

HTH.

Dave